# Height '100%' of div inside table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to make `height:100%` inside table cell actually i want to give margin between table cell so that's why i'm using '`.table-separator`' class for table in which i use margin because i can't use margin in table cell but '`.table-separator`' class height is not '`100%`'. I'm using `Bootstrap`.

**This is current condition:**

[image: this is current condition]

**But i want like this:**

[image: and i want it like this]

**Code**

**CSS**

```
.table-separator{
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    height:100%;
}
.compare-table>thead{
    border-bottom:none;
}
.compare-table>thead>tr>th:last-child .table-separator{
    margin-right:0px;
}
.compare-table>thead>tr>th{
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0;
    width:25.2%;
    border-bottom:0px;
}
.compare-table>thead>tr>th input{
    font-weight:normal;
}
.compare-table>tbody>tr>th,
.compare-table>tbody>tr>td{
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    height:inherit;
}
.compare-table>tbody .table-separator{
    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid #CDCDCD;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<table class="table compare-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><div class="table-separator">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default small-panel ns vonset2">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading small-heading">
                                                        <h3 class="text-normal text-uppercase no-m no-p">Rivals</h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body"> 
                                                        <!-- rivals list -->
                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled row ps-row bordered-list rl">
                                                            <li class="col-xs-12"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                <div class="row ps-row">
                                                                    <div class="col-xs-3 ps-col"><img src="http://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-s7--.jpg" width="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                                                                    <div class="col-xs-9 ps-col flex">
                                                                        <h2 class="no-m no-p fa-16 text-normal text-left text-capitalize">Samsung Galaxy J5 Compare With Samsung Galaxy J7</h2>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                </a> </li>
                                                            <li class="col-xs-12"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                <div class="row ps-row">
                                                                    <div class="col-xs-3 ps-col"><img src="http://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-s7--.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                                                                    <div class="col-xs-9 ps-col flex">
                                                                        <h2 class="no-m no-p fa-16 text-normal text-left text-capitalize">Samsung Galaxy J5 Compare With Samsung Galaxy J7</h2>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                </a> </li>
                                                            <li class="col-xs-12"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                <div class="row ps-row">
                                                                    <div class="col-xs-3 ps-col"><img src="http://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-s7--.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                                                                    <div class="col-xs-9 ps-col flex">
                                                                        <h2 class="no-m no-p fa-16 text-normal text-left text-capitalize">Samsung Galaxy J5 Compare With Samsung Galaxy J7</h2>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                </a> </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                        <!-- / rivals list --> 
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></th>
                                        <th> <!-- compare with -->

                                            <div class="table-separator">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default small-panel ns vonset2">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading small-heading">
                                                        <h3 class="text-normal text-uppercase no-m no-p">Compare with</h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <form class="row pm-row relative voffset2 vonset2">
                                                            <div class="form-group col-xs-8 ps-col no-mb">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="compare-search" placeholder="modal name or part of it...">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-xs-4 ps-col">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12">Search</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="panel srch-sug hidden">
                                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                                    <div class="row pm-row bordered-col">
                                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 pm-col">
                                                                            <div class="pm-row row">
                                                                                <h4 class="pm-col col-xs-12">Devices</h4>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <ul class="list-unstyled no-mb">
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                            </ul>
                                                                            <div class="pm-row row"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                <div class="pm-col col-xs-12 sug-footer more-result text-right"> More Reviews Results<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right pl5"></i> </div>
                                                                                </a> </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <!--/ compare with --> 
                                                <!-- comapre device -->

                                                <div class="panel panel-default small-panel ns devic-panel">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading small-heading">
                                                        <h3 class="text-normal no-m no-p">Samsung Galaxy J7</h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- device box -->
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled no-mb row pm-row voffset2 vonset2">
                                                            <li class="col-xs-6 ps-col"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-s7--.jpg" width="137"></li>
                                                            <li class="col-xs-6 ps-col">
                                                                <ul class="list-unstyled dmenu">
                                                                    <li><a href="">Review</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Specs</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Read Opinions</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Pictures</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="">360<sup>&deg;</sup> View</a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--/ device box --> 
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <!--/ compare device --> </th>
                                        <th><!-- compare with -->

                                            <div class="table-separator">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default small-panel ns vonset2">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading small-heading">
                                                        <h3 class="text-normal text-uppercase no-m no-p">Compare with</h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <form class="row pm-row relative voffset2 vonset2">
                                                            <div class="form-group col-xs-8 ps-col no-mb">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="compare-search" placeholder="modal name or part of it...">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-xs-4 ps-col">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12">Search</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="panel srch-sug hidden">
                                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                                    <div class="row pm-row bordered-col">
                                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 pm-col">
                                                                            <div class="pm-row row">
                                                                                <h4 class="pm-col col-xs-12">Devices</h4>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <ul class="list-unstyled no-mb">
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                            </ul>
                                                                            <div class="pm-row row"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                <div class="pm-col col-xs-12 sug-footer more-result text-right"> More Reviews Results<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right pl5"></i> </div>
                                                                                </a> </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <!--/ compare with --> 
                                                <!-- comapre device -->

                                                <div class="panel panel-default small-panel ns devic-panel"> <a href="javascript:;"> 
                                                    <!-- Empty box -->
                                                    <div class="panel-body text-center text-muted"> <i class="fa fa-mobile voffset2"></i>
                                                        <p>Add a device to compare</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- Empty box --> 
                                                    </a> </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <!--/ compare device --> </th>
                                        <th><!-- compare with -->

                                            <div class="table-separator">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default small-panel ns vonset2">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading small-heading">
                                                        <h3 class="text-normal text-uppercase no-m no-p">Compare with</h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <form class="row pm-row relative voffset2 vonset2">
                                                            <div class="form-group col-xs-8 ps-col no-mb">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="compare-search" placeholder="modal name or part of it...">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-xs-4 ps-col">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12">Search</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="panel srch-sug hidden">
                                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                                    <div class="row pm-row bordered-col">
                                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 pm-col">
                                                                            <div class="pm-row row">
                                                                                <h4 class="pm-col col-xs-12">Devices</h4>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <ul class="list-unstyled no-mb">
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                                <li class="media sug-list"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                    <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/68x83"></div>
                                                                                    <div class="media-body">
                                                                                        <h5 class="arimo media-heading">Samsung Galaxy J5</h5>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </a> </li>
                                                                            </ul>
                                                                            <div class="pm-row row"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                                                                <div class="pm-col col-xs-12 sug-footer more-result text-right"> More Reviews Results<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right pl5"></i> </div>
                                                                                </a> </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <!--/ compare with --> 
                                                <!-- comapre device -->

                                                <div class="panel panel-default small-panel ns devic-panel"> <a href="javascript:;"> 
                                                    <!-- Empty box -->
                                                    <div class="panel-body text-center text-muted"> <i class="fa fa-mobile voffset2"></i>
                                                        <p>Add a device to compare</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- Empty box --> 
                                                    </a> </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <!--/ compare device --> </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><div class="table-separator main-heading">Cameras:</div></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><div class="table-separator">Camera:</div></th>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">16 megapixels</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">16 megapixels</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">9 megapixels</div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><div class="table-separator">Flash:</div></th>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">LED</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">LED</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">N/A</div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><div class="table-separator">Pxiel density:</div></th>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">518 ppi</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">518 ppi</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">222 ppi</div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><div class="table-separator">Technology:</div></th>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">Super AMOLED</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">Super AMOLED</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">N/A</div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><div class="table-separator">Screen-to-body ratio:</div></th>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">Super AMOLED</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">Super AMOLED</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">N/A</div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><div class="table-separator">Dimensions:</div></th>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">186.9 x 108.8 x 8.7 mm (7.36 x 4.28 x 0.34 in)</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">186.9 x 108.8 x 8.7 mm (7.36 x 4.28 x 0.34 in)</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">186.9 x 108.8 x 8.7 mm (7.36 x 4.28 x 0.34 in)</div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><div class="table-separator">Features:</div></th>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non tellus porta ante laoreet consequat.</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">Curabitur ut tellus maximus, ornare urna sed, rhoncus nulla. Donec viverra diam vehicula lectus tincidunt, a tincidunt urna tempor.</div></td>
                                        <td><div class="table-separator">Sed fringilla molestie lectus. Integer euismod hendrerit tortor tempor auctor.</div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

change below CSS

```
.compare-table > tbody > tr > th, .compare-table > tbody > tr > td {
 border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
 height: inherit;
 padding: 0;
}
.compare-table > tbody .table-separator {
  /* border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;*/
  padding: 8px;
}
tr {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this is not solution not working actually i think got my question wrong i want to give spacing between `table-cell` that's why i'm using `.table-separator` class for giving margin for `table-cell`. i want to `height:100%` of `table-separator` class inside `table-cell`.

Comment: Thanks mate..i am happy that if you got solution

Comment: yeah i use `border-spacing` and control it vertically and horizontally.